# im using the web browser import and i want to figure out if i can run a google link in incognito from webbrowser. is that possible?

Tags: python

I'm writing out a code that opens up all necessary tabs using the webbrowser module so that I don't have to open them all manually when I open my pc, but one of the links I want it to open in incognito mode (all the links are google links) is this possible? I don't want all the code to open on incognito mode I just want the Microsoft Teams URL to open in incognito. Thanks in advance.

my code:

```
import webbrowser
import time

webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/')
time.sleep(0.3)
webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com/')
time.sleep(0.3)
webbrowser.open('https://teams.microsoft.com')
```

Comment: fwiw, you can just put all the URLs into a bookmark directory and open all the members of the directory (with a middle-click or right-clicking an selecting to do so)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specify the browser executable with the appropriate command line arguments to start it in incognito mode. The exact flag may vary by browser. Firefox, for example, takes the `-private-window` flag to start in incognito mode.

```py
import webbrowser
import time

firefox_path = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

incognito_browser = webbrowser.get(firefox_path + ' -private-window %s')

webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/')
time.sleep(0.3)
webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com/')
time.sleep(0.3)
incognito_browser.open('https://teams.microsoft.com')
# ...could use now incognito_browser to open additional sites as desired.
```

The `'%s'` is substituted with the URL during the call to `open` and must be present for `get` to recognize that a command line invocation is being supplied rather than a named browser instance, e.g. 'opera'.